# Is it possible to watch the value of a memory location using the Visual Studio Debugger's Watch window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Yes, I know there are four Memory windows, but I much prefer the display of a single value in the watch window, and I'm wondering if it's possible to specify a memory location to watch in the watch window.

Putting the address by itself just evaluates to the address in hex.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to watch a particular memory location then you need to tell the debugger the type of the object that lives in that location.  Instead of just `0x00aabbcc` use `(SomeType*)0x00aabbcc`.  Once the debugger knows the type of the memory location it will treat it just like a typed local and display values accordingly

Comment: I wish VS wouldn't try to be so smart, and require the data type be known to see what's at the memory location.

I'd rather it be a little dumb and just show me a hex dump at the memory location  :P

Comment: Well it has the Memory window for that already. Just drag and drop a variable there (or paste a hex address) and it will show you the raw memory state.

Answer (score 1):

Check the official site [answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx), which works as well as the other answers given to this question :).
On that page, the section "Following a Pointer Through Memory" says:

> In native code applications, you can use register names as live
>   expressions. For example, you can use the stack pointer to follow the
>   stack.
>
> *To follow a pointer through memory*
>
> 1. In the **Memory** window **Address** box, type a pointer expression. The pointer variable must be in the current scope.
>      Depending on the language, you might have to dereference it.
> 2. Press **ENTER**. Now, when you use an execution command such as **Step**, the memory address that is displayed will automatically change as the pointer changes.

Comment: "In the Memory window Address box, type a pointer expression." What, exactly, is a pointer expression? Nothing I try works.

Comment: A pointer expression could be something like:`*(int*)(ebp+0ch)` .It treats ebp+0ch as a pointer to int and then dereference it.