# Debugger how to only see values not memory addresses of variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

As of late I have been working extensively with struct and classes  in visual studio.Most of them have  a lot of values witch makes them hard to track in the watch windows while debugging because the watch windows and the floating watch windows ( the one you can pin , dont know precise term ) always show the memory address which obscures the view of the values. Is there a way to make it so that the watch windows only show the values and not memory addresses

Comment: You can write your own instructions for the debugger on how to view your custom types https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx

Comment: @ Blackwolf23, any update? Would you please let me know that latest information about this issue? Could you get any useful information from my suggestion?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the custom natvis would be a workaround.

But if the debugger knows the type of the memory location, I think it can display the value.

Reference:

[Is it possible to watch the value of a memory location using the Visual Studio Debugger's Watch window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023602/is-it-possible-to-watch-the-value-of-a-memory-location-using-the-visual-studio-d)

In addition, using format specifiers in watch window would be helpful for you to visit the value format:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx