# Viewing double bit pattern in Visual Studio C++ Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I'm working with IEEE-754 doubles, and I'd like to verify that the bit patterns match between different platforms. For this reason I would like to see the bit pattern of a double in the Visual Studio C++ Debugger.

I've tried [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2019), but they don't seem to allow me to format a double as anything which would allow me to see the bit pattern.

One way I finally found was to use Memory View and enter the address of the variable (`&x`) in the address field. This allows me to set for instance 8-bit integer hex display, which gives me what I need. But is there any other more convenient way of formatting a double this way in the debugger?

Comment: I think you could create [a nativs file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019) with the the settings of bit pattern and please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221735/debugger-how-to-only-see-values-not-memory-addresses-of-variables).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT a natvis file helps when you're working with a custom type, like a class wrapping a double, or a union of a `double` and a `long long`. But I don't think it's possible to change the format of a standard type, and even if it's possible then it's not a good idea since all variables of that type will be affected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To view the exact binary floating-point value you should print the it as hexadecimal with [`%a`/`%A`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) or [`std::hexfloat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) instead of examining its bit pattern

```
printf("Hexadecimal: %a %A\n", 1.5, 1.5);
std::out << std::hexfloat << 1.5 << '\n';
```

However if you really need to view the actual bit pattern then you just need to reinterpret the type of the underlying memory region like `auto bits = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(doubleValue)`. You don't need to open the Memory View to achieve this, a simple cast would work in the Watch window. So to get the bit pattern of `double` and `float` use `*(__int64*)&doubleValue,x` and `*(int*)&floatValue,x` respectively. Strict aliasing does occur but you don't actually need to care about it in MSVC debugger
<sub>Note that `__int64` is a built-in type of MSVC so you might want to use `long long` instead. Typedefs and macros like `uint64_t` won't work while watching</sub>

Alternatively you can access the bytes separately by casting to `char*` and print as an array with `(char*)&doubleValue, 8`, `(char*)&floatValue, 4` or `(char*)&floatingPoint, [sizeof floatingPoint]`. This time strict aliasing doesn't occur but the output may be less readable

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! I had missed that you could cast values directly in the watch window. Another example is `*(uint64_t*)&x,bb`, which gives bit view.